# Kotlin public constant is not accessible in other Java class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my Kotlin class A, I have a public constant defined, like:

```
class A {
    companion object {
        val TESTVALUE = "MY TEST VALUE"
    }
    ....
}
```

And in my other Java class B, I am trying to use it, like:

```
class B {

    private void testFunction() {
        String testValue = A.Companion.TESTVALUE
        // 'or'
        String testValue = A.TESTVALUE

        .....
    }
    ....
}
```

The error that I get is: 'TESTVALUE has private access'

[image]

Comment: Did you import the package ?

Comment: yes, its in my imports

Comment: try instantiating. ClassName obj = new ClassName(); then access it.

Comment: i just marked the kotlin class open and then extended the java class and accessed the variables.

Comment: I do not want to mark my class open, is there any other way?
Also, I was able to access this same variable in other Kotlin class.

Comment: In java class, it can be accessed as a function call

Comment: Yeah add @kotlin.jvm.JvmField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JvmField. Instructs the Kotlin compiler not to generate getters/setters for this property and expose it as a field. See the Kotlin language documentation for more information.

make sure you also reference fields created from a non-static context.

A.java

```
 class A {

    private void testFunction() {
        String testValue = B.TESTVALUE;
        System.out.println(testValue);
    }
};
```

B.kt

```
 class B {
     companion object {
         @kotlin.jvm.JvmField

         val TESTVALUE = "MY TEST VALUE"
     } }
```

Answer (score 5):

To access companion object fields from Kotlin class in Java class, you need to provide an annotation to Java reads appropriately. This annotation is `@JvmField`.

As shown in Kotlin docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-fields)

```kotlin
class A {
   companion object {
      @JvmField
      val TESTVALUE = "MY TEST VALUE"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. Do you know what to do if I want to have "public static"? I've tried "@JvmStatic" but then it's no longer public. I've tried both "@JvmField" and "@JvmStatic" but it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `@JvmField` annotation.

Read more here:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-fields

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify the Kotlin class (e.g. it's an auto-generated file) it should be ok retrieve a field by adding `get` the variable name.

A.kt

```
    public class DateTime {
      public companion object {
        public val type: CustomScalarType = CustomScalarType("DateTime", "java.util.Date")
      }
    }
```

B.java

```java
    private void testFunction() {
        String testValue = DateTime.Companion.getType();
    }
```